# Initially checked checkboxes value does not pass in controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of subjects coming from the controller which are populating checkboxes. Some of the checkboxes are checked intially, I have a edit button. When I click the update button, an alert should pop up, and the alert should show the checked subject's ids. But the problem is, when I load the page , and then if I click the update button, the initially checked subject ids do not pass to the controller. It works only if I uncheck those check boxes and recheck them. Here is my code snippet.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


        <script>

            var myApp2=angular.module("myModule2",[]);

            myApp2.controller("controller2",function($scope){

$scope.message="test";

$scope.Subjects=[
    {SubjectId:1,SubjectName:"Bangla"},
    {SubjectId:2,SubjectName:"English"},
    {SubjectId:3,SubjectName:"Math"},
    {SubjectId:4,SubjectName:"Science"},
    {SubjectId:5,SubjectName:"BGS"},
    {SubjectId:6,SubjectName:"Religious"},
    
    
];




$scope.SubjectIds=[2,5];



$scope.subjectModel = {};

$scope.edit = function () {

    var checkedSubjects = [];
    for (var k in $scope.subjectModel) {
        if ($scope.subjectModel.hasOwnProperty(k) && $scope.subjectModel[k]) {
            checkedSubjects.push(k);
        }
    }

    //do your stuff with the ids in `checkedBooks`
       alert(checkedSubjects);
}

});



        
        </script>
       
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myModule2" ng-controller="controller2">

    


        
    Subjects:
    <div ng-repeat="subj in Subjects">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subjectModel[subj.SubjectId]" ng-checked="SubjectIds.indexOf(subj.SubjectId)!=-1"/>{{subj.SubjectName}}



    </div>

    <div>

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update" id="updt" ng-click="edit()"/>
    </div>



    </body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was improper use of `ng-model`.

**First:** To work `ng-model` properly you have to create proper instances of the variables which is created by the code and sets its value `true or false` depends on whether the ids exists in the variable `$scope.Subjects[i]`:

```
$scope.subjectModel = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Subjects.length; i++) {
  $scope.subjectModel[$scope.Subjects[i].SubjectId] 
  =  $scope.SubjectIds.indexOf($scope.Subjects[i].SubjectId) > -1 ? true:false;
}
```

**Second:** the edit function is changed whether the checkbox is checked or not by using the following modified code:

```
for (var k = 0; k < $scope.subjectModel.length; k++) {
        if ($scope.subjectModel[k]) {
            checkedSubjects.push(k);
        }
    }
```

**Third:** To load data dynamically, you need to call `$scope.updateChkBox();` after `$scope.Subjects = pl.data;` The modified `loadSubjects` function given below:

```
function loadSubjects() {
        var promiseGet = crudService.getSubjects();


        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { 
                $scope.Subjects = pl.data;
                $scope.updateChkBox();
            },
            function (errorPl) {
                $log.error('failure loading Subjects', errorPl);
            });


 }
```

> Please check the final working code snippet:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


        <script>

            var myApp2=angular.module("myModule2",[]);

            myApp2.controller("controller2",function($scope){

$scope.message="test";

$scope.Subjects=[
    {SubjectId:1,SubjectName:"Bangla"},
    {SubjectId:2,SubjectName:"English"},
    {SubjectId:3,SubjectName:"Math"},
    {SubjectId:4,SubjectName:"Science"},
    {SubjectId:5,SubjectName:"BGS"},
    {SubjectId:6,SubjectName:"Religious"},
    
    
];




$scope.SubjectIds=[2,5];



$scope.subjectModel = [];
$scope.updateChkBox = function (){
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Subjects.length; i++) {
    $scope.subjectModel[$scope.Subjects[i].SubjectId] 
    =  $scope.SubjectIds.indexOf($scope.Subjects[i].SubjectId) > -1 ? true:false;
  }
}
$scope.updateChkBox();

 function loadSubjects() {
        var promiseGet = crudService.getSubjects();
 
 
        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { 
                $scope.Subjects = pl.data;
                $scope.updateChkBox();
            },
            function (errorPl) {
                $log.error('failure loading Subjects', errorPl);
            });
 
 
 }

$scope.edit = function () {

    var checkedSubjects = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.subjectModel.length; k++) {
        if ($scope.subjectModel[k]) {
            checkedSubjects.push(k);
        }
    }

    //do your stuff with the ids in `checkedBooks`
       alert(checkedSubjects);
}

});



        
        </script>
       
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myModule2" ng-controller="controller2">

    


        
    Subjects:
    <div ng-repeat="subj in Subjects">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subjectModel[subj.SubjectId]" ng-checked="SubjectIds.indexOf(subj.SubjectId)!=-1"/>{{subj.SubjectName}}



    </div>

    <div>

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update" id="updt" ng-click="edit()"/>
    </div>



    </body>




</html>
```

Comment: This works fine in the above case. But I am trying to load the $scope.SubjectIds from database and also loading $scope.Subjects from database. When I am doing the same thing in that case, I am facing the same problem as stated before. Here is the controller [controller](https://pastebin.com/Sh8xct7j)

Comment: And , here is the  HTML Code [view](https://pastebin.com/fJ7ASCnZ) @I.Ahmed